# Why doesn't Blazor support List.Add? What is the alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Why cant I run the following code in a Blazor component in the @Code section:

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();
dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
```

This code runs fine in a console app. It won't even compile in Blazor.  How do I add items to this list in Blazor?  In my final solution, I need to forEach through another list of objects to get the values I need to fill the final list.

Comment: I think you mean `var dinosaurs = new List<string>()`

Comment: `var dinosaurs = new List<string>()` doesn't compile.

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: @Fabio, why does `var dinosaurs = new List<string>()` mean anything?  How is that different from the OP's post?  To be clear, `List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();` is exactly equivalent to `var dinosaurs = new List<string>();`.

Comment: @KirkWoll, comment was addressed to the original code sample.

Comment: @Fabio gotcha, thanks, missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post more of your code.

Try this.

```
@code {

    List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
        dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
    }
}
```

`dinasaurs` is a **field** of your components **class**.

You can manipulate it from within a method.

Comment: I figured it out before I saw your answer.  I did exactly what you did and it worked great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian Parker's answer shows why your code didn't compile: you can't run methods in the declarations section of your code.

If you really want to initialize those values, then try:

```
List<string> dinosaurs  = new List<string>
            {   "Tyrannosaurus",
                "Amargasaurus",
                "Mamenchisaurus",
                "Deinonychus",
                "Compsognathus"   };
```

It looks nicer anyway, right? :D

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Actually I want to loop through a collection and load it from the collection.  You are right, I need to call the dinosaurs.Add method in a function.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I figured it out before I saw your answer.  I'm totally new to Blazor and I appreciate your help. I'll probably be blundering around asking stupid questions for a while.

Comment: We're all new to Blazor to some degree.  I've learned more in these forums trying to brainstorm together with people than I did studying alone.  So-- I hope you DO keep asking. :D